# ADB Amulator Running SDK 29 Remount

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator, mobile-development

**Hi friends,**
Recently I've created a new AVD instance via Android Studio that runs SDK 29 (Android 10).
Before version 29 I could:

1. Start the AVD from the command line.
2. Switch to root.
3. Remount
4. Copy an alternative hosts file to AVD's etc/hosts

For some reason I can't do that in with SDK 29 and after I run "./adb remount" command, I get the out put below.
What does it mean and how can I overcome this problem?

```
Skip mounting partition: /product_services
Skip mounting partition: /product
Skip mounting partition: /product_services
Skip mounting partition: /product
Skip mounting partition: /product_services
Skip mounting partition: /product
Skip mounting partition: /product_services
Skip mounting partition: /product
Skip mounting partition: /product_services
Skip mounting partition: /product
Skip mounting partition: /product_services
W Disabling verity for /system
E Skipping /system
Skip mounting partition: /product
Skip mounting partition: /product_services
Skip mounting partition: /product
Skip mounting partition: /product_services
Skip mounting partition: /product
Skip mounting partition: /product_services
Skip mounting partition: /product
Skip mounting partition: /product_services
Skip mounting partition: /product
Skip mounting partition: /product_services
Skip mounting partition: /product
Skip mounting partition: /product_services
Skip mounting partition: /product
Skip mounting partition: /product_services
Skip mounting partition: /product
Skip mounting partition: /product_services
Skip mounting partition: /product
Skip mounting partition: /product_services
Skip mounting partition: /product
Skip mounting partition: /product_services
Skip mounting partition: /product
Skip mounting partition: /product_services
/system/bin/remount exited with status 7
remount failed
```

Comment: Did you solve this? I have the same problem....

Comment: Not yet. Just waiting for the fix.

Comment: For me it worked updating the SDK Tools.See if it helps or if it's something related to this.